# How can I create a registeration form connected with an xml webservice?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, httprequest

I have to create a registration form in my app. It should be connected to the web service. How do I create it? Are there any good tutorials about this?

Comment: how registration form connected to web service,you send only data or information to web service

Comment: @NANNAV: yes , i send only the registration details to web service

Answer (score 1):

You can send only data to web service... e.g If you have text fileds in your form then you can make a method in which you can pass your link and in link you can pass the value of your text field... for example:

```
-(void)sendData
{
 NSString *registeruser = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yourlink//username=%@",yourTextfiled.text];
   NSLog(@"registeruser...%@",registeruser);
}
```

and call this method where you want.. If you want to call this method on Register Button then make button action and call this method.. for example..

```
 -(IBAction)RegisterAction:(id)sender
 {
   [self sendData];
 }
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: where you pass data to web service,you only assign string in self data