# Registration and Login form Creation With xml web service in iphone App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a registeration form connected with an xml webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872698/how-can-i-create-a-registeration-form-connected-with-an-xml-webservice)

I've to create a registration and login form in connection with web service. How can i send the registration details in to web service? And how can i log in using the username and password from web service? Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly learn the basic of Web Service [here](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)

This article will give you a good understanding of how to communicate with XML web services from within your iPhone application, and the examples will provide a solid foundation for consuming other web services in your own projects.

http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=97963e2d-37a5-4e48-b434-3fced80d2b55

Example:

```
-(UITextField*) customTextfield:(NSString*)fieldType textName:(NSString*)str initFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
        UITextField *customField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    customField.delegate = self;
    customField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    customField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        customField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    customField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    customField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
    customField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    customField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    customField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
    customField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    customField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(str, nil);
    customField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    return customField;
}



 - (void)viewDidLoad
    { 

        txtfname = [self customTextfield:@"" textName:@"" initFrame:CGRectMake(120, 75, 160, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:txtfname];

        txtlastname = [self customTextfield:@"" textName:@"" initFrame:CGRectMake(120, 115, 160, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:txtlastname];

        txtemail = [self customTextfield:@"" textName:@"" initFrame:CGRectMake(120, 155, 160, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:txtemail];

        txtpwd = [self customTextfield:@"" textName:@"" initFrame:CGRectMake(120, 195, 160, 30)];
        txtpwd.secureTextEntry=YES;
        [self.view addSubview:txtpwd];

        txtRePwd= [self customTextfield:@"" textName:@"" initFrame:CGRectMake(120, 235, 160, 30)];
        txtRePwd.secureTextEntry=YES;
        [self.view addSubview:txtRePwd];
    }
```

**On Form Submit**

```
-(void) fieldValidate
{
    NSString *emailRegEx =@"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *regExpred =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
    BOOL myStringCheck = [regExpred evaluateWithObject:txtemail.text];

    if ([txtfname.text length]==0) {
        [self callAlert:@"Please Enter First Name"];
        [txtfname becomeFirstResponder];
        return;
    }
    else if ([txtlastname.text length]==0) {
        [self callAlert:@"Please Enter Last Name"];
        [txtlastname becomeFirstResponder];
        return;

    }
    else if(!myStringCheck){
        [self callAlert:@"Email address should be in yourname@domainname.com  format"];  
        [txtemail becomeFirstResponder];
        return;
    }
    else if ([txtpwd.text length]==0) {
        [self callAlert:@"Password should have atleast 1 characters"];
        [txtpwd becomeFirstResponder];
        return;
    }
    else if ([txtRePwd.text length]==0) {
        [self callAlert:@"Password should have atleast 1 characters"]; 
       // [txtRePwd becomeFirstResponder];
        return;
    }
    else if (![txtpwd.text isEqualToString:txtRePwd.text])
    {
        [self callAlert:@"Password And Repassword Mismatched"];
        [txtpwd becomeFirstResponder];
        return;
    }

    [txtfname resignFirstResponder];
    [txtlastname resignFirstResponder];
    [txtemail resignFirstResponder];
    [txtpwd resignFirstResponder];
    [txtRePwd resignFirstResponder];


    NSString *Restrqst = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<user>\n"
                          "<account_attributes><first_name>%@</first_name></account_attributes>\n"
                          "<lastName>%@</lastName>\n"
                          "<email>%@</email>\n"
                          "<password>%@</password>\n"
                          "<password_confirmation>%@</password_confirmation>\n"
                          "</user>\n",txtfname.text,txtlastname.text,txtemail.text,txtpwd.text];  

    NSURL *RestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.xxxx.com/signup"];

  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:RestURL];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    request.shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge = YES ;
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml"];
    [request appendPostData:[Restrqst dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];

   }
```

Comment: Hi, i've already done some xml parsing apps. I didn't create a registration forms yet. i don't know how to send username,password etc to web service.

Comment: try with the above example

Comment: thank you laxonline. i'll try with this code

Comment: this code is working. thanks a lot frnd

Answer (score 0):

For the registration form :

You have to do simple XML parsing, In which you will execute your link and pass the data which user will fill during the registration and then you have to send that data to the web-service through the XML parsing

Comment: how? plz give me a sample code

Comment: Do you know XML parsing?

Comment: In parsing where you pass the link,In that link you have to pass the data